# Excel - Rank value based on range (X is the Yth highest value)

Tags: excel, vlookup, points

I'm wondering if someone could tell me if the following is possible, and if it is, how one would go about achieving it please.

I am working on a event points table. For example think of a race, if a person finishes first they get 100 points, 2nd 99 points etc. There are 2 championships, an open championship which includes everyones and a members championship for a select number of people.

I have a completed open championship table which contains a column for the names of people who are racing, and a column for the number of points they achieved in that event.

In a seperate sheet I have a similar formatted table but with a column of 'members' names. What I would like to do is pull through the points from the open standings sheet but then recalculate the points rewarded to give the highest ranked member 100 points, 2nd 99 etc.

So for example if member John Doe scored 76 points in the open championship but was the highest ranked member in that event, they would receive 100 points in the members championship.

The only way I can think I could go about this is to pull the numbers through from the open champ sheet to the members champ sheet using vlookup, then rank the numbers based on a range, so '97' from '100, 97, 65' is the 2nd highest value, then take that value (-1) from 100. So 100-(2-1)=99 points

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can there be ties in either an individual race or the combined values??

Comment: @pnuts Open championship table is populated, im just not sure how I would go about recalculating for the members table.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent No, no ties :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this copied down might suit:

```
=CHOOSE(RANK(B1,B:B),100,99,98,97,96,95,94,93,92)
```

with the values extended as necessary, assuming columnB has the members' points from the open standing (and the names may be in ColumnA).

Comment: Thanks, this helps alot. Is there anyway to work this out without pre-populating the the points in the members table please?

Comment: Already using a vlookup for column B, but just rather keep things as tidy as possible to be honest.